# Why is typescript giving an error when my conditionals only return the types described

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

### I am defining the types as an array of cretedEvents or string this gives me th following error:

> Type '(parent: User, args: InputShapeFromFields<InputFieldMap<"InputObject" | "Arg">>, context: { currentUser: User; }) => "No events created" | (string | createdEvents[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<User, InputShapeFromFields<InputFieldMap<"InputObject" | "Arg">>, { currentUser: User; }, createdEvents[] | null | undefined, "No events created" | (string | createdEvents[])[]>'.
> Type '"No events created" | (string | createdEvents[])[]' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<readonly MaybePromise[]> | null | undefined'.
> Type '"No events created"' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<readonly MaybePromise[]> | null | undefined'.

What it seems to be referring to is that the field I am creating is not assignable to the User type.

I have tried

1. Returning parent.createdEvents by itself
2. If undefined return null, undefined and an empty array.

None of these work however **If I add any as an option on the user cretedEvents type definition it works so I am assuming that is the location of the problem *Listed directly below***

```js
export class User {
    _id: ObjectId;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password?: string;
    availableWeights?: number[];
    createdEvents?: createdEvents[] | string;
    signedUpEvents?: userSignUp[];



    constructor(id: ObjectId, name: string, email: string, password?: string, availableWeights?: number[],
        createdEvents?: createdEvents[] | string, signedUpEvents?: userSignUp[]) {
        this._id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.availableWeights = availableWeights;
        this.createdEvents = createdEvents;
        this.signedUpEvents = signedUpEvents;
    }
}
```

**Like I said if I add | any to the end of the createdEvents field the error goes away**

### Here is where I get error on resolve:

```js
 createdEvents: t.field({
            type: [createdEvents],
            resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
                if (parent.createdEvents == undefined || parent.createdEvents == null || parent.createdEvents.length == 0) {
                    return "No events created";
                } else {
                    return parent.createdEvents;
                }
            }
        }),
```

### Here is the class definition I use as the type throughout the code:

```js
export class createdEvents {
    _id: ObjectId;
    eventName: string;
    eventDate: Date;
    eventDescription: string;
    cost?: string;
    eventLink?: string;
    weights?: weightsForUserCreatedEvents[];

    constructor(_id: ObjectId, eventName: string, eventDate: Date, eventDescription: string, cost?: string, eventLink?: string, weights?: weightsForUserCreatedEvents[]) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.eventDate = eventDate;
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.eventLink = eventLink;
        this.weights = weights;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `parents.createdEvents` is already an array why are you then wrapping it in braces? `return [parent.createdEvents];`

Comment: Or why would you ever return an error message there for that matter. Either return an array or undefined.

Comment: I was just trying to simply display the error even if I implement what you said I still have the same issue.

Comment: Nevermind switching the types to allow undefined worked. But why can't I allow it to be a string? Or maybe an empty array for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution Courtesy of *Michel Floyd*

Use undefined instead of the string

```js
export class User {
    _id: ObjectId;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password?: string;
    availableWeights?: number[];
    createdEvents?: createdEvents[] | undefined;
    signedUpEvents?: userSignUp[];



    constructor(id: ObjectId, name: string, email: string, password?: string, availableWeights?: number[],
        createdEvents?: createdEvents[] | undefined, signedUpEvents?: userSignUp[]) {
        this._id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.availableWeights = availableWeights;
        this.createdEvents = createdEvents;
        this.signedUpEvents = signedUpEvents;
    }
}
```

```js
        createdEvents: t.field({
            type: [createdEvents],
            resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
                if (parent.createdEvents == undefined || parent.createdEvents == null || parent.createdEvents.length == 0) {
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    return parent.createdEvents;
                }
            }
        }),
```